# Modify a String Based on a Numeric Input

Tags: php

I would like to modify a string after getting a numeric input from the user.
Here are some examples of how the string should be modified based on the numeric input:

```
String is "WELCOME"
An input of 0 produces WELCOME
An input of 1 produces W*L*O*E
An input of 2 produces W**C**E
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
$numb=$_GET['number']+1;
$str=$_GET['string'];
$temp="*";
$len=strlen($str);

for($i=0;$i<=$len;$i=$i+$numb)
{
    echo $str[$i];  
}
```

Comment: what does the number that you input means ?

Comment: The input number is the number of characters to mask in a row.

Comment: input  number is numeric only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numb = $_GET['number'] + 1;
$str = $_GET['string'];
$sep = '*';
$len = strlen($str);
if ($numb == 1) {
    echo $str;
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if ($i % $numb == 0) {
            echo $str[$i];
        } else {
            echo $sep;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the same solution I had come up with. +1

Comment: Except now that I've edited his question and see that he wants `*` for every skipped character, it's wrong.